# MySQL deadlocks when trying to drop large fulltext index

Tags: mysql, myisam, full-text-search

I'm trying to just drop a 500mb fulltext index on an older 4.1 MySQL MyISAM table.

When I do it, the cpu pegs to 100% and sits like that for over 10 minutes.

This cannot be normal, right?  I gave up and just restarted mysql and index is still there.

There is no message in the error log.

Any other approach I can try?

---

Nevermind, it took 30 minutes and double the database size in free disk space in the end.

I guess even drop is very slow for some reason (I know building can be, but drop?)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old bug in mysql:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2364